# What does an empty echo in bash script mean?

Tags: linux, bash

I have this script:

```
if [ -n "$running_processes" ]
      then echo
      echo $service:
      echo
      echo "$running_processes"
      echo
      echo "lines: $(echo "$running_processes" | wc -l)"
      echo
      echo "=========="
fi
```

What does actually the echo with no string after that do?

Comment: It will just print a newline character.

Comment: What do you think it does if you run it?

Comment: Thank you, I can't run it on my machine. I asked just to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

From the info page:

> `echo' writes each given STRING to standard output, with a space
>   between each and a newline after the last one. Synopsis:
>
> ```
> echo [OPTION]... [STRING]...
> ```

Since there are no strings that follow, the command will just print an empty line.